# Subtract in xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I have problem with subtract in this example file:

```
<EVENTS>
<ROW ID="204" ID_PLACE="1" EVENT_TYPE="B" EVENT_NAME="TEST1" EVENT_ID="201">
<PRICE>
<ROW EVENT_PRICE="165,00"/>
</PRICE>
</ROW>
<ROW ID="205" ID_PLACE="1" EVENT_TYPE="P" EVENT_NAME="TEST1" EVENT_ID="201">
<PRICE>
<ROW EVENT_PRICE="125,00"/>
</PRICE>
</ROW>
</EVENTS>
```

Her is a relevant piece of my XSLT:

```
<xsl:for-each select="EVENTS/ROW/PRICE/ROW">
  <xsl:variable name="event_b">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="EVENT_TYPE=B">
        <xsl:value-of select="EVENT_PRICE" />
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="event_p">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="EVENT_TYPE=P">
        <xsl:value-of select="EVENT_PRICE" />
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="number($event_b) - number($event_p)" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

I have to subtract event_price with type P from the corresponding one with type B. In this example I want to get a result 40, and output it into the result tree, but it isn't working.  What's wrong?

Comment: Post your code, so we don't have to guess what your problem is. -- Hint: you need to translate the comma to a point in order for the price to be recognized as a number.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead. Also make sure your code is **complete**  - see: [mcve].

Comment: I need result of this 165,00-125,00=40,00. I don`t have a problem with format of number. I have problem with show a result of subtract in one node which name is event_price_subtract.

Comment: "*I don`t have a problem with format of number.*" I believe you do. We'll know for sure when you post your code.

Comment: I edit my post and attached xslt that I use for subtract.

Comment: Should I use xsl:copy function to get a variable event_b and event_p. If I should do this tell me how? Please help me I am a novice in xslt, to this time I only write very simple xsl transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to convert strings to numbers, but those strings are not formatted correctly for XSL / XPath / XSI numbers.  Specifically, the `number()` constructor recognizes only the period ('.') character as a decimal separator, but your input strings seem to use commas (',') in that role.

If you cannot correct the data to follow prevailing convention for representing decimal numbers, then you'll need to account for the variant convention in your stylesheet.  You can do this with the `translate` function.

Before you even get there, however, you have severe problems in your stylesheet structure, among them:

- your outer `xsl:for-each` does not make sense.  You are iterating over individual (inner) `<ROW>`s, but you intend to handle *pairs* of corresponding rows.  A convenient context for that would be the closest common ancestor, though there are other ways to approach the problem.
- Your `select` and `test` expressions are attempting to refer to child elements where you mean to refer to attributes.
- In some places, your tests are comparing to (non-existent) child elements instead of string values.

Overall, you've made it much harder than it needs to be.  For the input you've presented, you might do something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="EVENTS">
    <!-- Note @attribute_name syntax for referring to attributes -->
    <!-- Note quoted form for string literals -->
    <!-- Note that these expressions are evaluated relative to the EVENTS element
         matched by this template -->
    <!-- Note no iteration: each value wanted is identified via an
         appropriate XPath expression -->
    <!-- Note use of a select expression to specify the variables' values.
         That doesn't make much difference in this particular case, but it
         _is_ significant. -->
    <xsl:variable name="event_b"
        select="ROW[@EVENT_TYPE = 'B']/PRICE/ROW/@EVENT_PRICE"/>
    <xsl:variable name="event_p"
        select="ROW[@EVENT_TYPE = 'P']/PRICE/ROW/@EVENT_PRICE"/>

    <!-- Note use of translate() to translate commas to periods before converting
         to numbers -->
    <xsl:value-of select="number(translate($event_b, ',', '.')) - number(translate($event_p, ',', '.'))" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```