# In subtract in xslt 1.0 I get only result from last node

Tags: xml, xslt

I still have problem with subtract in xslt:
My source code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1250"?>
<RAKS_R3>
<EXPORT ID="1" EXPORT_DATE="2017-06-21">
<EVENTS_DOCUMENTS>
<ROW ID="202" DATE="2017-01-31" DOC_CODE="WST" DOC_NUMBER="WST 0001/17">
<EVENTS>
<ROW ID="204" EVENT_ID="205" EVENT_ACC_NUM="400-01-01" EVENT_TYPE="B">
<PRICE>
<ROW EVENT_PRICE="1333,23"/>
</PRICE>
</ROW>
<ROW ID="205" EVENT_ID="205" EVENT_ACC_NUM="400-01-01" EVENT_TYPE="P" >
<PRICE>
<ROW EVENT_PRICE="1376,06"/>
</PRICE>
</ROW>
<ROW ID="209" EVENT_ID="204" EVENT_ACC_NUM="400-01-01" EVENT_TYPE="B" >
<PRICE>
<ROW EVENT_PRICE="1676,19"/>
</PRICE>
</ROW>
<ROW ID="210" EVENT_ID="204" EVENT_ACC_NUM="400-01-01" EVENT_TYPE="P">
<PRICE>
<ROW EVENT_PRICE="1730,04"/>
</PRICE>
</ROW>
</EVENTS>
</ROW>
</EVENTS_DOCUMENTS>
</EXPORT>
</RAKS_R3>
```

Xslt 1.0 is like this:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1250"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output encoding="Windows-1250" method="xml"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
   <xsl:key name="p" match="ROW[@EVENT_TYPE='P']" use="@EVENT_ID" />
   <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="R">
      <xsl:element name="EXPORT">
        <xsl:attribute name="DATE_M"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="VER">9</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:element name="DOCUMENTS">
          <xsl:element name="DOCUMENT"> 

          <xsl:for-each select="RAKS_R3/EXPORT/EVENTS_DOCUMENTS/ROW">

            <xsl:attribute name="DOC_NUMBER"><xsl:value-of select="@DOC_NUMBER"/></xsl:attribute>

            <xsl:element name="DECRS">
            <xsl:for-each select="EVENTS">

              <xsl:element name="DECR">
              <xsl:for-each select="ROW[@EVENT_TYPE='B']">
                <xsl:attribute name="ID">
 <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
 </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="WN">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@EVENT_ACC_NUM"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="MA">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'070-07'"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="AMOUNT">


    <xsl:variable name="B" select="PRICE/ROW/@EVENT_PRICE"/>
    <xsl:variable name="P" select="key('p', EVENT_ID)/PRICE/ROW/@EVENT_PRICE"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Btrans" select="translate($B, ',', '.')" />
    <xsl:variable name="Ptrans" select="translate($P, ',', '.')" />
    <xsl:variable name="Diff" select="number($Btrans - $Ptrans)"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="$Diff" />

                </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:attribute name="AMOUNT2"></xsl:attribute>
              </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>             
          </xsl:for-each>  
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And on the result I get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1250"?>
<R>
<EXPORT DATE_M="" VER="9">
<DOCUMENTS>
<DOCUMENT NUMBER_N="1" ID_INS="" ID_ACC_DOC="14" TYPE_DOC="WST" NAME_DOC="WST" SYMBOL="M" ACC_DATE="2017-01-31" DOC_NUMBER="WST 0001/17" DOC_DATE="2017-01-31" SELL_DATE="2017-01-31">
<DECRS>
<DECR ID="2" WN="400-01-01" MA="070-07" AMOUNT="-53.85" AMOUNT2=""/>
</DECRS></DOCUMENT>
</DOCUMENTS>
</EXPORT>
</R>
```

But I need something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1250"?>
<R>
<EXPORT DATE_M="" VER="9">
<DOCUMENTS>
<DOCUMENT NUMBER_N="1" ID_INS="" ID_ACC_DOC="14" TYPE_DOC="WST" NAME_DOC="WST" SYMBOL="M" ACC_DATE="2017-01-31" DOC_NUMBER="WST 0001/17" DOC_DATE="2017-01-31" SELL_DATE="2017-01-31">
<DECRS>
<DECR ID="1" WN="400-01-01" MA="070-07" AMOUNT="-42.83" AMOUNT2=""/>
<DECR ID="2" WN="400-01-01" MA="070-07" AMOUNT="-53.85" AMOUNT2=""/>
</DECRS></DOCUMENT>
</DOCUMENTS>
</EXPORT>
</R>
```

Why I get result only from last difference with ID=2 where is ID=1?? Can anyone help me?? I wrote on this forum third time, I get very good answer from michael.hor257k([Subtract in xslt 1.0 with sorting nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44653798/subtract-in-xslt-1-0-with-sorting-nodes)), but still I have problem with that transformation.

Comment: Please reduce the code to the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem, and add the expected result.

Comment: Code reduced, I can't do this more.

Comment: Now I can't get value of key which name is "p".

Comment: In xslt that you give me before there was a template only for events. I thought that I use this in my advanced case without any problem, but It wasn't so easy that I supposed.

Comment: Ok, I know where was the problem. I should use for-each before the Decr strats. When I move this one level before there is all right. Sorry for this question, but I haven't seen this thing.

Comment: If you no longer need / want an answer to this as-yet unanswered question then you should delete it.